# Change the CSS Based On the Language

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I am using a Google Translate in my website, to show the content in 2 different languages German, and Spanish other than the original content(English). Now as soon as select other language there are some miss-placements in the contents and text due to the change in length of the words and also i need to change few images and logo which is written in English.

my question is 
How to change CSS based on the Language?

Some information about the site: It is a simple website developed using plain HTML, CSS, Javascript and jQuery.

Comment: I am not getting how to start up with this.. i just tried searching for language detection using Javascript. no fruit full result so for.

Comment: Friendly tip: never use machine translation in production. It's often worse than having no translation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using simple html or any framework, use of automatic translators is not appreciated some time it does not translate correctly, Try making different css files for each langage and make ur site in different language. if you are using some cms etc you can achieve this easily. So when you click on spanish flag it should go to index-sp and it will load style-sp.css.

Hope it will help.

Comment: I am not using any framework or CMS and Thank you Abdul Basit, Palash, Praveen & juhana for your Valuable answers and comments. you are right Abdul i will create separate Style sheet for different language And that is the better idea i think.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a solution to switch from 2 different **css** files based on **rtl(ar)** and **ltr(en/pt)** and there's a really easy and quick solution that worked for me:

```
<environment include="Development">
    @if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft)
    {
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/styles.rtl.min.css" />
    }
    else
    {
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/styles.min.css" />
    }
</environment>
```